# What is the fastest way to update existing records with a sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I've got a data set with a primary key, a foreign key and an empty sequence value. What is the fastest way of adding a sequence number to the data based on the foreign key?

`QuestionConditionId` is my primary key, `QuestionId` is foreign key. This is what the data looks like after selecting with an order by on `QuestionId`:

[image]

After the update my data should look like this:

[image]

I could write a loop for this, but I'm hoping for something smaller and more efficient. Any ideas?

Comment: you are lukcy in sql server to have `row_number` :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionId 
                                       ORDER BY QuestionConditionId ) AS RN
         FROM   YourTable)
UPDATE T
SET    Sequence = RN
```

But keeping this `Sequence` column synchronised after inserts, updates, deletes may be more hassle than it is worth. You can also use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculate at `SELECT` time rather than storing it.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for